# Flutter: How to locate the currently visitble Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

How can an Async task (that does not have access to the current context) find the currently visible Scaffold?

With Network requests that could fail after the user navigate away from a page, I'd like to show an error using a toast or bottom sheet.  I could pass the current context to the network function but that value might be invalid by the time the network call completes.

Comment: The most simple/common solution is to have a series of centralised methods, which you import on the view that you want to handle network issues, that handle showing a toast/bottom sheet, and pass the current context of that view to those methods.

Comment: My understanding is that the context will become invalid if the user navigates away from the current page.  If that is correct then this does not solve the problem

Comment: As I said in my comment, you pass the current context to the methods that may invoke a visual warning of network changes.